# How can I find a function that accurately matches a x,y scatter plot

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have a complicated piecewise function(see below), that I use in a spreadsheet to determine what a subcontractor get paid on a particular job.

*For example if a job is worth $$270 dollars the subcontractor gets paid 60% of that. Or if a job is worth $18 the subcontractor keeps 95% of the value.*

**I have a few problems:**

- The spread sheet gets really slow when there are a ton of these equations in there
- the equation isn't smooth, so a subcontractor who does a job worth $$269.00 makes $174.85, while a subcontractor who does a job worth $291.41 makes $174.85. This doesn't make any sense.

**Attempts:**

- I tried to come up with a few equations, by graphing them in excel as a scatterplot and using the "add trendline" function. This failed and seemed like the function it came up with never very accurate.
- I also tried to just tinker with a formula for a long time and the best I could come up with was: -7.1257 * ln(x + 0.9999) + 100.6672 . It was pretty accurate at the low and some what accurate at the higher end, but is in accurate in the middle.

**Questions**

- Do I just need to give up and find some constant based off of statistically the profit I want to make? ( about 20% on average)
- Is there a formula that really accurately fits this piecewise?
  -

[image: This is a scatter plot with 10,000 x,y points, and the piecewise function in question]

Comment: Sounds like you want a smooth function to avoid the anomalies you mention. Do you want it to go through the middle of what you have now, or should it be closer to the minimum or the maximum values there?

Comment: For people later viewing this. I can post the actual formula that I use now. I did eventually use an online regression tool to come up with a more accurate formula. Unfortunately, it still needs to be piecewise with at least two exits/comparison-conditions: (1) x>269, (2) x≤269. As there are no formulas with a horizontal asymptote that also fit the general trend. Thus Exit (1) is 60%, and Exit (2) is my formula. Let me know if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

I placed points in the middle of your intervals, created a scatter plot, and then used the "Add Trendline" function with degree = 3 or 4 or 5. Using a higher degree gives a closer fit, but the curve starts to get more "wiggly".

The degree 5 curve is

```
y = -1E-12x5 + 1E-09x4 - 3E-07x3 + 5E-05x2 - 0.0049x + 0.9983
```

You need to do something special when $x > 269$ because there's no way to get a polynomial curve to flatten out and become a horizontal line.

Comment: I'm having trouble reading your response. Can you use carrot "^" symbols to denote power, & asterisks "*" do denote multiplication and x as the functional variable. I know "E" means "10^" I attempted to us -10^-12*x^5 + 10^-9*x^4 - 3*10^-7*x^3 + 5*10^-5*x^2 - 49*10^-4*x + 9983*10^-4 but this doesn't match the data.

Comment: Use Excel to generate the function. What I typed is just an illustration. When you see the results, you might decide to use some other function. Excel gives you many options.

Comment: It will be very difficult to match the "steps" in your original graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a quadratical minimization to a polinomial. For example, Levenberg-Marquardt method fit data to a polinomial of arbitrary degree and give good results (is used generaly with continous functions). Try different degrees. If your domain is well covered more or less in all subzones can give you good results.